# How to load multiple markers from json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a jquery mobile map application, I have map.html, map.js and map.json files as given below

```js
function initialize() {
        var latitude = 57.95,
            longitude = 14.65,
            radius = 8000, //how is this set up
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
            bounds = new google.maps.Circle({center: center, radius: radius}).getBounds(),
            mapOptions = {
                center: center,
                zoom: 9,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: false
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(center, radius, map);
    }

    function setMarkers(center, radius, map) {
        var json = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({ 
                'async': false, 
                'global': false, 
                'url': "./map.json", 
                'dataType': "json", 
                'success': function (data) {
                     json = data; 
                 }
            });
            return json;
        })();

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.25,
                strokeWeight: 1.0,
                fillColor: '#ffffff',
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                clickable: false,
                map: map,
                center: center,
                radius: radius
            });
        var bounds = circle.getBounds();

        //loop between each of the json elements
        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 



            if(bounds.contains(latLng)) {
                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.content
                });
                infoBox(map, marker, data);
            }
        }

        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    }

    function infoBox(map, marker, data) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Creating a closure to retain the correct data 
        // Note how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {
          // Attaching a click event to the current marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        })(marker, data);
    }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
[{ 
    "lat": 57.95, 
    "lng": 14.65, 
    "content":"test content1" 
}, 
{ 
    "lat": 57.9, 
    "lng": 14.6, 
    "content":"test content2" 
}, 
{ 
    "lat": 57.85, 
    "lng": 14.55,
    "content":"test content3"
}]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </script>
    <script src="./map.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

But in my code the markers are not seen.... when I tried to run a single html file without any external .js and .json file it worked but with this code I am not able to run..

i need to know where am going wrong and also neeed help on:
1. showing multiple markers in the map
2. on clicking the marker it should show the message in content tag

waiting for help...thanks in advance...

Comment: Does your browser console show any errors?

Comment: this is the error am getting

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/map/map.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.b.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5b.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ map.js:22setMarkers @ map.js:32initialize @ map.js:16
map.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of nullsetMarkers @ map.js:48initialize @ map.js:16

Comment: You need to test `ajax`requests with real webserver. You can't request files  from `file:///`, because this would be a security problem. While it is possible to lower the security settings in the browser to allow access to `file:///` you shouldn't do that because allow malicious scrips to access your local files.

Comment: @t.niese  i understand wt ur trying to say.. if that is the case, then how do i include the external *.json file to the project?? thank you

Comment: As Vadim suggests in the answer below, you can install a web server and load from `localhost`. One easy way to do this is to install Python (either 2.x or 3.x) and then open a command prompt window, `cd` to your directory, and run the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Then you can load your page from `http://localhost:8080`. Plus, now you have Python which is useful for other things too.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the example, most likely the reason why you are getting this error since you are trying to opening html page directly from the browser (therefore to load `map.json` via file protocol).

Basically there two options available:

**Option 1**

You can either install a web server and access your page on `localhost` or upload the `map.json` somewhere on the web and change the url to `http://example.com/map.json`

**Option 2**

Allow the browser to access local files, for example in Chrome you could specify `allow-file-access-from-files` flag, for example:

```
> .\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

please review this code for both solution,

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };



// Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
    ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>']
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}
```

Reference link: http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

Answer (score 0):

I found the [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) and *GeoJSON* features blocks are an easier way to draw static points or regions on the map. I recommend replacing your data file with GeoJSON & using the *map.data.loadGeoJson(url)* call.

The [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) link also explains how to load the URL. It talks about CORS and your issues.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, 
run this in cmd to start chrome by letting it access local file.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

Rest all is correct, i could display multiple markers and onclick an info window would open..

for more readability, you can change the latlang initialized and the radius. in the above code snippet only 2 markers are visible although there are 3 in json file. increase the radius to see the 3rd marker
thanks to all for help